# Carrierwave MiniMagick PDF Preview

Tags: carrierwave, minimagick

Uploading files in my Rails app via Carrierwave / MiniMagick.  Trying to create previews of the first page of PDFs.  Ran into a few issues:

1) Some PDFs convert but the background is all black.  Images and comments are visible

2) Some PDFs result in this error:

```
ImageProcessing::Error - Source format is multi-layer, but destination format is single-layer. If you care only about the first layer, add `.loader(page: 0)` to your pipeline. If you want to process each layer, see https://github.com/janko/image_processing/wiki/Splitting-a-PDF-into-multiple-images or use `.saver(allow_splitting: true)`.:
```

My codes looks like this:

```
version :thumb do
  process :convert => 'jpg'
  process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]
  def full_filename (for_file = model.file.file)
    "preview_thumb.jpg"
  end
end
```

Not clearly understanding which MiniMagick command line arg to add and how to add them.

Comment: Ever come to a solution?